# How do I replace all the unique string values with one word in a specific column? Not just fillNA

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, fill

In python I would like to replace all the written values in a column with the word 'Other'.
This is kinda what my data looks like:

```
User   Strawberry   Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
1      Strawberry   Raspberry
2                   Raspberry  Wildberry  Banana
3      Strawberry   Raspberry  Wildberry  Blueberry
4      Strawberry                         
5                   Rasberry              Apple
6      Strawberry   Rasberry              
7                              Wildberry  Blueberry
8      Strawberry   Rasberry   Wildberry  Watermelon
```

I would like to replace all the different values in Other with just the word other. However as in my real sample I have even more answer options that I showed here for Other, I would like a more automated method than just taking every single word and replacing it with other and I want to leave the blank spaces empty.

I want my result to look like this:

```
User   Strawberry   Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
1      Strawberry   Raspberry
2                   Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
3      Strawberry   Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
4      Strawberry                         
5                   Rasberry              Other
6      Strawberry   Rasberry              
7                              Wildberry  Other
8      Strawberry   Rasberry   Wildberry  Other
```

Answer (score 0):

##### replacing only "Other"

Use a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html).

If you have NaNs:

```
df['Other'] = df['Other'].mask(df['Other'].notna(), 'Other')
```

Or in place:

```
df.loc[df['Other'].notna(), 'Other'] = 'Other'
```

Output:

```
   User  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
0     1  Strawberry  Raspberry       None   None
1     2         NaN  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
2     3  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
3     4  Strawberry        NaN       None   None
4     5         NaN   Rasberry        NaN  Other
5     6  Strawberry   Rasberry       None   None
6     7         NaN        NaN  Wildberry  Other
7     8  Strawberry   Rasberry  Wildberry  Other
```

For empty strings:

```
df['Other'] = df['Other'].mask(df['Other'].ne(''), 'Other')
```

Or in place:

```
df.loc[df['Other'].ne(''), 'Other'] = 'Other'
```

Output:

```
   User  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
0     1  Strawberry  Raspberry                  
1     2              Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
2     3  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
3     4  Strawberry                             
4     5               Rasberry             Other
5     6  Strawberry   Rasberry                  
6     7                         Wildberry  Other
7     8  Strawberry   Rasberry  Wildberry  Other
```

##### replacing several columns:

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
# ['Strawberry', 'Raspberry', 'Wildberry', 'Other']

df[cols] = df[cols].notna().mul(cols)
```

Output:

```
   User  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
0     1  Strawberry  Raspberry                  
1     2              Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
2     3  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
3     4  Strawberry                             
4     5              Raspberry             Other
5     6  Strawberry  Raspberry                  
6     7                         Wildberry  Other
7     8  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using replace:

```
df = df.replace({'Other':{r'\w+':'Other'}},regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   User  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
0     1  Strawberry  Raspberry                  
1     2              Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
2     3  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
3     4  Strawberry                             
4     5              Raspberry             Other
5     6  Strawberry  Raspberry                  
6     7                         Wildberry  Other
7     8  Strawberry  Raspberry  Wildberry  Other
```